# Why is a primary node needed in pBFT algorithm for consensus?

Tags: distributed-systems, consensus, byzantine

Why is primary needed in pBFT algo? Since many issues of viewchange etc. come up because primary may be faulty - is it possible to have a version of pBFT which doesn't have nodes assigned as primary? Or does having a primary node fulfill a function which is crucial?